# Spaces in a Directory/Filename that is used in a Batch Script For Statement

Tags: batch-file

Why does this batch script work...

```
@echo off
for /F %%a in ('dir /b F:\Temp\*.txt') do set TestFileName=%%~nxa 
echo %FileName%
pause
```

But this one does not...

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq" %%a in ('dir /b "F:\Temp Folder\*.txt"') do set TestFileName=%%~nxa 
echo %FileName%
pause
```

I know that it has something to do with the double quotes that I am using due to the spaces in the folder name.  But even after hours of searching the web and reading countless posts that are similar, I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it. And it is driving me CRAZY!!!

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: The option "usebackq" means that you have to use backquotes (a.k.a. back ticks or grave accent or `\``) to run a command.  Change `'` to `\``.  The command `help for` discusses this.

Answer (score 1):

Three points here:

1- As "usebackq" imply: Use Back Quotes for command execution, so you must put ` instead of '.

2- Independently of the above, this code:

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq" %%a in (`dir /b "F:\Temp Folder\*.txt"`) do set TestFileName=%%~nxa 
echo %FileName%
pause
```

does NOT work either, because the shown variable FileName is NOT the same of the FOR command: TestFileName.

3- I strongly suggest you to NOT use a FOR /F command that execute another command (like DIR) if the base capabilities of simple FOR are enough for your needs. For example:

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("F:\Temp Folder\*.txt") do set TestFileName=%%~nxa 
echo %TestFileName%
pause
```

Previous code is not just easier to write and understand, but it run faster also.

Finally: previous code "works" in the sense that display *just the last file name*. If you want to display *all names* via a variable, then a different approach must be used.

I hope it helps...

Antonio